# convert localization of date using moment js

Tags: momentjs

This is very simple, But I can not do it.

I have the following string date in the javascript

```
start = "٠١/٢٦/٢٠١٧"
```

I need to convert it using moment.js to the following

```
start = "01/26/2017"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to use the right locale and follow the instruction about [*Changing locales locally*](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/) in the official docs.

Here a working example:

```js
var start = "٠١/٢٦/٢٠١٧";
moment.locale('ar');
var m = moment(start, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
console.log(m.locale('en-gb').format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/locale/ar.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/locale/en-gb.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was able to solve this problem, but in more complex way than your, I updated my code as you said, Any way thank you

Comment: You're welcome @HakamFostok, I tried to gave the best answer with the infomations you provided in your question.